# Need to combine two rows that are exactly the same with the exception of one column

Tags: sql

I have a large database where each month more data is added, in this database if a new user is added it creates a new row. The issue I have is that due to spelling error in the past which I have since corrected. The data is appearing as one row. What I need is for both rows to be combined under the one username.

I essentially would like to combine the totals for both of these rows. So in your example I would like all totals in the wrong row 'Jhon Smith' to be added to the correct row 'John Smith'. I could then delete the row that is wrong once I knew the values were all accounted for.

```
+------------------------------------------+------------+-------+----------+----------+
|                                          |  Username  | Miles |   Car    | Expenses |
+------------------------------------------+------------+-------+----------+----------+
| Correctly spelled row                    | John Smith |   200 | Peugeaut |     1000 |
| Incorrectly spelled row                  | Jhon Smith |    17 | Peugeaut |      500 |
| Total of both rows (what I want to show) | John Smith |   217 | Peugeaut |     1500 |
+------------------------------------------+------------+-------+----------+----------+
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Connor

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and [mre]. For SQL questions like this one, it is a good practice to include your [data structure as a table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post). You will also want to show what you have tried.

Comment: A user is entered twice, say, once as 'John Smith' and once mistakenly as 'Jhon Smith' and you want to get rid of the misspelled one? Then use `DELETE` on that row. Or am I misunderstanding things?

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I will try to add more detail in future posts. I essentially would like to combine the totals for both of these rows. So in your example I would like all totals in the wrong row 'Jhon Smith' to be added to the correct row 'John Smith'. I could then delete the row that is wrong once I knew the values were all accounted for. I will try and draw the table in another comment.

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTx6G.png  sorry couldnt attach image as only new

Comment: Even as a beginner you can edit your request and add the information there. I've done that for you. You are not supposed to link to images, but copy and paste your data. For formatting you can use https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/

Comment: Thank you thats really useful to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like all you need is an inner join on the two rows and to add the (however many) columns together, something along the lines of

```
update t set
    t.col1 = t.col1 + t2.col1,
    t.col2 = t.col2 + t2.col2,
    <rinse repeat>
    ...
from table t join table t2 on t2.Id=67890 <-- PK of the row to delete
where t.Id=12345 <-- PK of table, 12345 is the row you want to keep
```